# loading a heavy content website efficiently such that user suffer the least of latenncy

Tags: php, javascript, asp.net, ruby-on-rails

Past few days while observing few websites with heavy content I found very interesting thing..some websites handle it pretty well...

What I found was that they load the content user is looking for primarily on the website first and let the other content which requires a lot computation deliver slowly..

For example try opening facebook in new browser, that you haven't opened facebook for a while, so that we can observe without browser cache effect..**News feed will be loaded first on page and other stuff like ticker, chat, counting of notifications and messages, etc and even remaining news feeds follow later..**

**My Questions:**
1) What is actually happening here?? Because As per my knowledge web works as a request from client and one response from server with data..

2) How can I manage which parts to load first and ***start displaying without waiting for other data to be calculated on server..***

**P.S.**
I am currently working on php mainly, and will shift to rails shortly, so I am mainly concerned about answer specific to these languages, *if some technology specific part is there..* **Anyways all answers are most welcome as someday they will be useful..:)**

Comment: The core HTML page is just a skeleton, and the actual content is filled in after-the-fact via Javascript and AJAX calls back to Facebook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook is using something they call [BigPipe](https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=389414033919) to send parts of the page as they render.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript is the solution.

A starter for ten is the following link:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23768/Load-and-Display-Page-Contents-Asynchronously-with